# Complicated citation of sources

Tags: citations, citation-style

I am writing an essay and have to use the Chicago 17th edition notes and bibliography style.

One of my sources is a book. Within the book is a collection of 30 historical documents. Some of these documents are excerpts of direct primary sources, and some of them are excerpts of a separate secondary source citing a primary source. How would I cite these in my essay?

Here is a copy of the book I am using: https://www.scribd.com/document/667447666/Matteo-Ricci-and-the-Catholic-Mission-to-China-Ronnie-Po-Chia-Hsia

Essentially I just want to know how to cite this, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to err on the side of over-citation. There is no reason you can't have multiple citations at the end of a sentence. Cite the book (*your* original source) as well as the secondary source cited in the book. For historical documents, you may get away mentioning something along the lines of "x document as reproduced in *book*". But you could certainly include a reference to the original document if available. Either way, as long as proper credit is given and information/ideas can be traced back to their source, you have some leeway.

Comment: *There is no reason you can't have multiple citations at the end of a sentence.* FYI, I've seen several instances of 10+ citations at the end of a sentence, but off-hand I don't know the longest list I've ever seen. An extreme case that I do recall is the *Introduction* (pp. xiii-xv) of [this book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1439880476). Unless I've miscounted, [on p. xiii](https://books.google.com/books?id=caFX9VwE5NgC&pg=PR13) there is one list with 46 citations (middle of page) and another list with 47 citations (near bottom of page), and there is also a list with 20 citations on p. xv.